# HOW TO bind value to label asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i want to bind the colum value cumload value to label.but i am getting error (index outofrange exception wan unhandled by user code).so i tried to convert.Toint(dr1["cumload"]).tostring(),eventhough probleM is coming.cumload containing double

```
    SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr1.Read())
    {
        Label3.Text = dr1["cumload"].ToString();// this line problem
    }

    cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: dr1["cumload"] have value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of yours is causing problem because you're not checking whether that column has any value or not. Try it this way.

```
SqlDataReader dr1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr1.Read())
{
    Label3.Text = dr1.IsDBNull(dr1.GetOrdinal("cumload")) ? String.Empty : dr1.GetString(dr1.GetOrdinal("cumload"));
}

cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Hope it helps you.